# Iterating through ObservableCollection in order to find objects and return list of possible results by user input

Tags: c#, loops, observablecollection

I'm creating a Library application or so to say that has Bookcases which themselves have a collection of Shelves and Books. I'm working on the Books right now and I need a method that would iterate through a list based on user input and find list of possible objects by the input. For example if the user specifies that the search is by Genre and he puts in Fantasy then all the objects with genre "Fantasy" has to be displayed. 
So far I have got this: (A method that returns one book object that has been found but I need a list of books that have all of this).

```
public Book SearchSpecificBook(string selectedSearch, string input)
{
    switch (selectedSearch)
    {
        case "Title":
            foreach (var searchBook in BookContainer)
            {
                if (input == searchBook.Title  )
                {
                    return searchBook;
                }
            }
            break;
        case "Author":
            foreach (var searchBook in BookContainer)
            {
                if (input == searchBook.Author )
                {
                    return searchBook;
                }
            }
            break;
        case "Genre":
            foreach (var searchBook in BookContainer)
            {
                if (input == searchBook.Genre  )
                {
                    return searchBook;
                }
            }
            break;
        case "ISBN":
            foreach (var searchBook in BookContainer)
            {
                if (input == searchBook.ISBN)
                {
                    return searchBook;
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't already have it, add the following using statement:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Update your case statements like this one:

```
case "Title":
    return BookContainer.Where(x => x.Title == input).ToList();
```

EDIT:
You will also need to update the method to return

```
List<Book>
```

I should add, this assumes that BookContainer is a list or some other construct that implements IEnumerable or IQueryable (it should be since you are using it in a foreach).

Comment: Okay. I am having a bit of trouble with the adding a comment because it messes up the code. But basically, I tried your solution but now I am having trouble printing in the Console because even if I try to refer it to the ObservableCollection I have, it doesn't detect the objects inside.

Comment: Never mind. I fixed it. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This *may or may not be applicable*, but to make the most generic search function you could pass a search predicate to your function, then pass it to [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx). For example:

```
public Book SearchSpecificBook(Func<Book, bool> predicate)
{
    return BookContainer.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

Then call it from the outside like this:

```
Book book = bookcase.SearchSpecificBook(x => x.Title == "50 Flavors of Regex");
```

If this is not possible (for example you wish to search by different parameters depending on an outside condition), you could still improve your code readability by using [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx) in your switch statement:

```
switch (selectedSearch)
{
    case "Title":
        return BookContainer.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Title == input).ToList();
    // ...
}
```

Another thing I would consider making an [`enum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) of possible search parameters. This would add [strong typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing) to your search:

```
public enum BookSearchType
{
    Title,
    Author,
    Genre,
    ISBN
}
```

Then you can switch over your possible `BookSearchType` values like this:

```
public Book SearchSpecificBook(BookSearchType selectedSearch, string input)
{
    switch (selectedSearch)
    {
        case BookSearchType.Title:
            return BookContainer.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Title == input).ToList();
        case BookSearchType.Author:
            return BookContainer.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Author == input).ToList();
        // ...
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(selectedSearch));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)